# List by email address responses to Cognito Form

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm beginning to build up quite a database of completed forms in Cognito and it would save me a ton of work if there were some way to list form submissions by email address so that I could see all forms completed by a specific customer.

I know I could somehow cobble this together using Zapier or something but I'm not a programmer and, anyway, I can't see how I could produce a listing out of a SQL table and then hyperlink directly into one specific form submissions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can quickly filter on specific email addresses (or anything else) by entering the value in the search area when managing entries in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

We are also in the initial staging of planning [Public User Profiles](https://trello.com/c/u5WcAYkd/103-public-user-profiles) which should effectively solve the bulk of your needs by making it easy for you to view entries for specific external users (your customers) across multiple forms.  This will be our focus once we have released all of the features currently in progress.